# Semi-direct product $C_p : C_3$

Tags: group-theory, gap, semidirect-product

I want to construct the group $C_p:C_3$ in GAP, where $p$ is prime and $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Originally, I come up with this

```
for p in [1..1000] do  
    if IsPrime(p) and (p mod 3)=1 then  
        N:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,p);  
        G:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,3);  
        AutN:=AutomorphismGroup(N);  
        for i in [1..Size(AutN)] do  
            f:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(G,AutN,
                 GeneratorsOfGroup(G),[Elements(AutN)[i]]);  
            if f<>fail then  
                NG:=SemidirectProduct(G,f,N);  
                Print(IdGroup(NG),"\n");  
            fi;  
        od;  
    fi;#IsPrime and p mod 3 =1  
od;#p
```

which works fine, but then I had a thought.

At present, this will also find the direct product, which is the case f: G -> Aut(N) is the trivial homomorphism. I could get rid of this by explicitly excluding it, or alternatively, if the identity element of `AutN` is always `Elements(AutN)[1]` I could just run the `i` loop from `[2..p-1]`.

We will also find each non-trivial semidirect product twice, because the map sending the generator of Cp to the automorphism x, and the map sending the generator of Cp to x^-1, will give isomorphic semidirect products.

So I revised the code a little but am still unsure of how to get rid of the non-trivial semidirect product twice and now it does not work in GAP.

```
for p in [1..1000] do  
    if IsPrime(p) and (p mod 3)=1 then  
        N:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,p);  
      G:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,3);  
        AutN:=AutomorphismGroup(N);  
        for i in [2..p-1] do  
            f:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(G,AutN,
                 GeneratorsOfGroup(G),[Elements(AutN)[i]]);  
            if f<>fail then  
                NG:=SemidirectProduct(G,f,N);  
                Print(IdGroup(NG),"\n");  
            fi;  
        od;
    fi;#IsPrime and p mod 3=1  
od;#p
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify: ALL the non-trivial semi-direct products $C_p\rtimes C_3$ are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: @verret yes, you're right.  But why does my second attempt of a code not run?

Comment: @ChrisG  A question "Why does my code not run" is typically perceived as rather lazy of the questioner and putting the effort of checking/reproduction on the person answering. In which way does your code not work? Do you get an error message? (If so, which one)?

Comment: I found the mistake.  I just thought a fresh pair of eyes would help find the error @ahulpke.  Nothing to do with being lazy.

Comment: @ChrisG But think about what you expect the "fresh pair of eyes" to do. They need to copy your (badly formatted, as it does not use code mode) commands line-by-line into the system, and then might need to figue out what the problem (wrong result? error message?) is. This ends up as a quiz "find out what I already observed" for the volunteer who responds. Why make them do extra work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code output every non-trivial semi-direct product exactly once, insert after the line **Print(IdGroup(NG),"\n");** the command of GAP **break;**
But better yet, instead of the loop, use the command **RootsMod( 1, 3, p);**